# Others Can't join Minecraft server

Tags: networking, server, java, minecraft

So I've recently started a new Minecraft server. and it works just fine locally and from another desktop (connected with the ip4) however. When I try to connect with the public IP address + port (example) 165.242.53.1:25565 it doesn't show.

I'm sure that I port forwarded well (I already ran a Minecraft server several times on windows) but I just can't figure out why it doesn't work.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 I believe.

Comment: If it works fine on your LAN, then it works fine. Your server doesn't care if a connection is LAN or WAN. Check your firewall, if any, to ensure you didn't deny access to WAN connections (you would have created that rule, it does not exist by default). Next stop is to check your port forwarding again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a port checker tool like [YouGetSignal](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) and see if you have properly configured your port forwarding. Run the Minecraft server and check if port 25565 is available on your IP address.